# get string value from item clicked in a listView

Tags: android, mysql, sql, listview, onitemclick

Hi i am new to android programming, i have make an Http post request to get json data from an external sql database and displayed my result in a lisView. i want to be able to retrieve the string value from a clicked item in the listView. Please any help with this will be much appreciated

Comment: Where is that sweet code of yours Sugar?

Comment: sugar can you post your adapter class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this, which has worked for me in the past:

```
String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

This is from within the `listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()` portion of your code.

If your strings are aggregated into one string, then try this:

```
//Let itemValue = "item1 item2 item3" for example:
String[] parts = itemValue.split(" ");
String part1 = parts[0]; // item1
String part2 = parts[1]; // item2
```

Comment: Thank you.. your answer have been So helpful.. each item contains more than one string values.. now What I want is to retrieve the values of the clicked item and store Them in string variables

Comment: Without your code, It is hard to determine what you mean. Also, if you think people have been somewhat helpful, give them a thumbs up ;)

Comment: I cant really give thumbs up because i cant see the options here on the mobile app.. but all the answers has helped me..

Answer (score 1):

Set OnItemClickListener on listview. See on below.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                String itemString=listView.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }
        });
```

Enjoy!!!...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String itemString=listView.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }

        });
```

Comment: Thank you.. your answer have been So helpful.. each item contains more than one string values.. now What I want is to retrieve the values of the clicked item and store Them in string variables